How do you increase the TTL of a twilio assigned task from the default 24 hours to 3 days
I am having an issue where assigned tasks in twilio are deleted after 24 hour. I need the tasks to live longer than that. Is there a way to do this? setting the timeout to 1209600 when creating the task has no effect for assigned tasks.
How do you increase the TTL of a twilio assigned task from the default 24 hours to 3 days
I am creating the tasks and passing the Timeout using the studio flow. Using the interactions API is not working either e.g
await client.flexApi.v1
      .interaction(attributes.flexInteractionSid)
      .channels(attributes.flexInteractionChannelSid)
      .invites.create({
        routing: {
          properties: {
            workspace_sid: "WSXXXXXX",
            workflow_sid: workflow_sid,
            queue_sid: task_queue_sid,
            worker_sid: known_worker_sid,
            task_channel_unique_name: 'chat',
            attributes: { ...attributes },
            timeout: 1209600,
          },
        },
      });


You can update the task 24 hours after the assignment. The update resets the timer of "task.system-deleted" will be triggered. For example, if the task was created in "2024-11-20 20PM" and assigned to a worker, if there's no update on it, it'll be finished at "2024-11-21 20PM," but if you update the attributes of the task in "2024-11-21 10PM," it'll be finished just in "2024-11-22 10PM." You can do it until the time of timeout configured to the task.

Tasks can be configured to live for up to 2 weeks; however, the TaskRouter limit documentation states that when a Task is assigned, the maximum time a Task can stay assigned to a Worker before being deleted by the system is 86400 seconds (24 hours). This limit cannot be changed.

Actually that is not true for assigned task. Like I said in the question, passing the timeout parameter is not working. I am creating the tasks using studio flow but some through the interactions (like in the edits above). Twilio is simply not respecting the timeout when the task is in the assigned status. For wrapping and unassigned, the time out is respected

Ah sorry I missed the part around assigned tasks.
Looking at the documentation for TaskRouter limits, the maximum amount of time a Task can stay assigned to a Worker before being deleted by the system (task.system-deleted) is 86400 seconds (24 hours)
I will update my answer to reflect this

You can also update the task 24 hours after the assignment. The update resets the timer of "task.system-deleted" will be triggered.
For example, if the task was created in "2024-11-20 20PM" and assigned to a worker, if there's no update on it, it'll be finished at "2024-11-21 20PM," but if you update the attributes of the task in "2024-11-21 10PM," it'll be finished just in "2024-11-22 10PM." You can do it until the time of timeout configured to the task.

Thanks @csevero. That seems like a more reasonable solution. I tried to listen for the task.system-deleted event, and recreating the task, but that is not always reliable as the conversation is at times closed by the overzelous task janitor
